# Bing Geocode api not working with Singapore addresses

Tags: bing-maps, bing, bing-api

I tried several valid address but bing map api is not returning a result:

http://dev.virtualearth.net/REST/v1/Locations?adminDistrict=Singapore&CountryRegion=SGP&postalCode=449269&addressLine=80%20Marine%20Parade%20Rd&key=mykey

any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are three ways to resolve your issue;

- Instead of passing in Singapore as an adminDistrict (i.e. state/province), pass it in using the locality property (city). Alternatively pass it in to both of those properties.
- Remove the postal code from the query.
- Instead of using a structured address, pass in your address as a query. This is recommended in the best practices and greatly increases the odds of a correct result being found: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn894107.aspx